# Calling Pushwoosh Remote API from Parse Cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pushwoosh

I want to send push notification from my Parse server(cloud code) using pushwoosh Remote API. I am trying to follow their [Guidelines Here](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/createmessage) but can't but I am getting 400 error code in return of request which means my request string is malformed.

**400 | N/A | Malformed request string (from [status codes here](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/createmessage#section-response-))**

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("LinkPost", function(request, response) {


Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/createMessage',
      data: JSON.stringify({
                     "request": {
                     "application": "APPLICATION_ID",
                     "auth": "AUTH_TOKEN",
                     "notifications": [{
                         "send_date": "now",
                         "ignore_user_timezone": true,
                         "content": "Hello world!"
                                      }]
                               }
                          }),
       dataType: 'json'


 }).then(function(httpResponse) {
          console.log(httpResponse.text);
          }, function(httpResponse) {
          console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
          });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ***never*** post your auth token or application id in public. I strongly suggest you to edit your post and remove the application id and auth token from it.

Now to the problem:

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest takes "body" as parameter instead of "data" as guided by pushwoosh $ajax post call

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("LinkPost", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/createMessage',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "request": {
                "application": "APPLICATION_ID",
                "auth": "AUTH_KEY",
                "notifications": [{
                    "send_date": "now",
                    "ignore_user_timezone": true,
                    "content": "Hello world!"
                }]
            }
        }),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
     console.log(httpResponse.text);
    }, function(httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    });
});
```